# Google Calendar API - Not showing calendar

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've downloaded the Google API Client and installed it on my Server. I set up my API and my client ID.
I configured the PHP file and now I'm trying to open it:
http://euotm.net/google-api-php-client/examples/calendar/simple.php

I signin using a Google Account, but then all I get is a code.

WHy does that happen? I need it to show a calendar.
I'm new to this API, so I really don't know much.

Thanks ahead,

Tom.

Comment: if you use Google client api it only get the feed from your calendar, it doesn't show any calendar, we can achieve it by using custom javascript full calendar

Answer (score 0):

Indeed google calendar api doesn't provide a display widget to integrate calendar to your application. The api only gives you the possibility to retrieve every details about your calendars and their events, and then you'll have to find a way to display it on your screen if you want a nice layout.

Answer (score 0):

have you

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
```

these files in your code ? i think you may miss it. what error, you are getting kindly make more sense about this

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. From what I've found so far, it looks like RadASM is right, but I was wondering what you moved on to in terms of which widget/gadget you used to display your actual calendar.

If you haven't found it yet, you may be looking for this:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/event/

Please let me know what you went with.

Answer (score 0):

RadASM is right. Google Calendar API provides well structured data for the calendars and calendar events, allowing data manipulation, too. Desiring your custom layout, you need to take care of it.

Here is a detailed explanatory article with full demo code within a single HTML file - [Easy and compact access to your Google calendars](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/55).